# zoomcharts - 1.5.1 hover over multiple links doesn't work

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts

I see that zoomcharts has come up with cool features in their latest update (1.5.1), but it has some bugs i believe...

**I am not able to hover over middle links in case of multiple links between two nodes. I can only hover over 1st and last link**

If you just copy paste the following code [here](https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/examples/data-sources/preloaded.html), you can test it yourself...

```
<script>
    var data = {
        "nodes":[
            {"id":"n1", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node1"}},
            {"id":"n2", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node2"}}
        ],
        "links":[
            {"id":"l1","from":"n1", "to":"n2", "style":{"fillColor":"red", "toDecoration":"arrow"}},
            {"id":"l11","from":"n1", "to":"n2", "style":{"fillColor":"red", "toDecoration":"arrow"}},
            {"id":"l111","from":"n1", "to":"n2", "style":{"fillColor":"red", "toDecoration":"arrow"}},
            {"id":"l114","from":"n1", "to":"n2", "style":{"fillColor":"red", "toDecoration":"arrow"}}
        ]
    };

    var t = new NetChart({
        container: document.getElementById("demo"),
        area: { height: 350 },
        data: { preloaded: data },
        info: {enabled: true, linkContentsFunction: function(data, link, callback) {
          return link.id;
        }}
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved in version 1.8.

Until it is released you can also use the nightly build from: https://cdn.zoomcharts-cloud.com/1/nightly/zoomcharts.js